# scala.Function0 running spark simple WordCount in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, bigdata, data-science

I am trying to run a simple program that counts words in scala with spark. I have done all the installation by myself in linux, and I can not execute it as I am having this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
at sbt.internal.inc.classpath.ClasspathFilter.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:74)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase$$anonfun$1.apply(KryoBase.scala:41)
at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase$$anonfun$1.apply(KryoBase.scala:41)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase.<init>(KryoBase.scala:41)
at com.twitter.chill.EmptyScalaKryoInstantiator.newKryo(ScalaKryoInstantiator.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:292)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newInstance(KryoSerializer.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.supportsRelocationOfSerializedObjects$lzycompute(KryoSerializer.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.supportsRelocationOfSerializedObjects(KryoSerializer.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager$.canUseSerializedShuffle(SortShuffleManager.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.registerShuffle(SortShuffleManager.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency.<init>(Dependency.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.getDependencies(ShuffledRDD.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.dependencies(RDD.scala:237)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getShuffleDependencies(DAGScheduler.scala:431)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getOrCreateParentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:380)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.createResultStage(DAGScheduler.scala:367)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:850)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1677)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Basically the code I am trying to execute is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkWordCount extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Spark Word Count")
    .getOrCreate()

  val lines = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    Seq("Spark Intellij Idea Scala test one",
      "Spark Intellij Idea Scala test two",
      "Spark Intellij Idea Scala test three"))

  val counts = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

  counts.foreach(println)
}
```

I think that it should be due to something with the spark and scala versions, but I can not find the good solution.

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "com.example.test"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
)
```

If I execute the same code in an spark-shell it works, I have installed the versions:

- scala: 2.11.8
- spark: 2.2.0
- sbt: 1.0.2

I have tried also with different scala versions, and spark, and everything, but does not work, could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance, 
Javi.

- When I execute the command sbt inside the project, It shows:

  Getting Scala 2.12.3 (for sbt)...

What I can not understand, as I am specifying the scala version in the build.sbt (scalaVersion := "2.11.8")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you are trying to run this code from Intellij Idea. If that's true main issue lies in Idea configuration.

Go to **File** > **Project Structures** > **Global Libraries** and check whether you have scala-library installed. Idea uses its own sources for libraries and SDK that's why everything works fine in shell.

I tried your code in pure sbt layout and it worked with exactly the same `build.sbt` and source files.

One little thing. Maybe Idea automatically stops all running spark sessions at the end of the run but I believe you have to explicitly stop active session. Just put `spark.stop()` at the end of your executable function or object.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks a lot for your help, I am using Intellij, but I am trying as well to run with sbt and it does not work as well. I have checked what you says and it has installed the scala-sdk 2.11.8, so everything looks good..., Finally I have created a new project, and mysteriously it works....

Comment: I was writing a comment about making a new project just to test whether it's a system-wise issue or just project related. Glad everything worked out for you. :)